# Find all my answers for a specific tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I can search on `user:me [sockets]` to find all questions that I've written for a specific tag.

But I would like a feature that could be used to find all questions that I've answered for a specific tag.

**Edit**

I noticed that `user:me [sockets]` found both questions that I've written and questions that I've answered. Consider this a request to only get questions that I've answered.

Comment: I don't get the difference between "all questions that I've **written**" and "all questions that I've **answered**"

Comment: a) I wrote the question. b) You wrote the question and I answered it.

Comment: ah, ok, I don't know how to search that, but for api, may be like this - http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/70386/tags/sockets/top-answers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can now do this using the `is:` operator (which will be added to the help page in the next build).  For example, the query you're after would be: `user:me [sockets] is:answer`, or so everyone can test it: [`user:70386 [sockets] is:answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:70386%20%5Bsockets%5D%20is:answer) ([try here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:70386%20%5Bsockets%5D%20is:answer))

The `is:` operator lets you specify `is:answer` or `is:question`, allowing you to get *only* those type of results.

Another example usage would be the reverse, all the questions you **asked** in that tag would be: [`user:70386 [sockets] is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:70386%20%5Bsockets%5D%20is:question) ([try here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:70386%20%5Bsockets%5D%20is:question)).

This is currently live, only the `/search` help text needs to be updated, which will happen on the next build.

Comment: Terrific. Maybe this is asking too much, but I'd find `is:comment` _extremely_ useful. (I'm often paging through my comments to find something specific, so `is:comment` in combination with `user:me` would help me a lot.)

Comment: @Hendrik - Unfortunately we don't index comments at all, if we change anything on that front I'll of course add it.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand - thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Why does this still not work on the entire StackExchange network? ... I mean to search on all all sites at once.